# chrome devtool : activate a specific source tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to open/activate a specific resource in the devtool source tab. I am aware of `ctrl+o`, but I'd like to do it programmatically.

Background: I use ExtJs and would like to create an extension that will open the js class file in devtools source when hovering/clicking on an extjs component.

Comment: Try using [chrome.devtools.panels.openResource](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#method-openResource) (you'll probably have to add a [devtools page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions) to access the API).

Comment: @wOxxOm: this is the right answer